# On Opening one dropdown the other drop down if it is opened should close

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add the logic of automatically closing an already opened drop-down menu, on opening the other menu. For example, I have opened feature-1 drop down, and while I click on feature-2 to open, feature-1 dropdown should close and vice versa.

```
const [expand1, setExpand1] = useState(false);
const [expand2, setExpand2] = useState(false);

             <ul>
                <li>
                    <div onClick ={() => setExpand1(!expand1)}>
                        <a onClick={() => openPane('1')} className="menu-item">
                        
                        <span>Feature-1</span>
                        <div className={`drop-down ${expand1 ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                        <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div></li>
                 <li>
                    <div onClick ={() => setExpand2(!expand2)}>
                    <a onClick={() => openPane('2')} className="menu-item">
                        <span>Feature-2</span>
                        <div className={`drop-down ${expand2 ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                        <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
               </li>
           </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding custom functions as `onClick` handlers and handle the logic there.

```js
const [expand1, setExpand1] = useState(false);
const [expand2, setExpand2] = useState(false);

const toggle1 = () => {
   if(expand2) setExpand2(false)
   setExpand1(!expand1)
}

const toggle2 = () => {
   if(expand1) setExpand1(false)
   setExpand2(!expand2)
}

             <ul>
                <li>
                    <div onClick ={toggle1}>
                        <a onClick={() => openPane('1')} className="menu-item">
                        
                        <span>Feature-1</span>
                        <div className={`drop-down ${expand1 ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                        <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div></li>
                 <li>
                    <div onClick ={toggle2}>
                    <a onClick={() => openPane('2')} className="menu-item">
                        <span>Feature-2</span>
                        <div className={`drop-down ${expand2 ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                        <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
               </li>
           </ul>
```

This is very unclean, but demonstrates the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using focus and blur. `<div>` is not automatically focusable, so you need to give it the `tabIndex` prop to make it focusable.

```
<div tabIndex="0">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Now, the `<div>` is focusable.

What you need to do next is give the `<div>` an `onFocus` and `onBlur` prop to hide or show the `<div>`.

```
const menuRef = React.useRef()
const [focusedIndex, setFocusedIndex] = React.useState(null)
const onFocus = (e, {index}) => setFocusedIndex(index)
const onBlur = (e, {index}) => {
  setFocusedIndex(null)
  // you can implement your own logic here
}

return (
  <div ref={menuRef}>
    {
      ['a', 'b'].map((val, i) => (
        <div 
          onFocus={(e) => onFocus(e, {index: i})}
          onBlur={(e) => onBlur(e,{index: i})}
          tabIndex="0"
          style={{display: focusedIndex === i ? 'block' : 'none'}}
          key={`${i}`}
        >
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  </div>
)
```